# где пишется дефис

Tags: орфография

**кое- -либо -нибудь -таки -ка -то** пишется через черточку. Это знакомо с детства. Что я пропустил?

Comment: Что именно вас интересует? Все слова пишутся через дефис( черточку). Дефис-черточка -это то же самое, если вас это интересовало.

Comment: @Vurshpelhappilio, вам стоит задавать вопрос более осмысленно. Очень трудно разгадывать, что вы хотели сказать и, соответственно, что пропустили.

Answer (score 1):

Частицы, которые внедряются в текст с использованием дефиса: **-нибудь, -то, -ка, -с, -кое, -либо, -таки, -кой, -де, -тка.**
Смотрите сами, что именно вы "пропустили".

Некоторые из них могут в определенных случаях писаться и раздельно, правила можете посмотреть тут.
http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.51

Answer (score 0):

Одобряю ответ участника "Morkovkin", только поправлю: **кое-, кой-**.
И добавлю ещё: **-кась, -ткась**.

*Кто-то, что-либо, чей-нибудь, кое-какой, скажите-ка, на-ка, на-кась, ну-ка, ну-кась, нате-ка, нате-кась, он-де, да-с, на-тка, на-ткась, ну-тко, гляди-тко.*